# Converting, or removing formatting of a CLOB?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to `SELECT` som data and on of the cols is a `CLOB`.

Im currently using `TO_CHAR(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(T.Tekst, 4000, 1))` but this outputs the clob, text format and all, something like this:

`{\rtf1\ansi\deff0\deftab254{\fonttbl{...` and the text faaar out there.

Is there a way so I only get the text, not all the formatting?

Comment: what is exactly stored in your CLOB column? it seems that it is stored in the DB with the formatting and all, TO_CHAR(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(T.Tekst, 4000, 1)) is doing its correct job in this case

Comment: TO_CHAR(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(T.Tekst, 4000, 1)) returned "{\rtf1\ansi\deff0\deftab254{\fonttbl{\f0\swiss\fcharset0 Arial;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Arial;}{\f2\fnil\fcharset0 Times New..." :(

Comment: @mcha DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(T.Tekst, 4000, 1) returned the same :(

Comment: because this is what is stored in your CLOB column, how this column is filled? and maybe if you provide a full example we can play with DBMS_LOB.INSTR too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: You can [write stored procedures in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chfive.htm). That would allow you to add a RTF parser to the database and convert the data to pure text in your SQL.

Note that the performance of this needs some loving attention. If you plan to search many gigabytes of text in a `SELECT`, a much better option would be to parse the RTF data in the code which fills the `CLOB` or create a new table which contains the data you need plus triggers to keep them up to date.